# problema al mostrar en la grilla del MatTableDataSource a partir de un json en Angular

Tags: angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se ve el json de consumo, el problema es al llenar la grilla en el MatTableDataSource me sale el error "ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function paginator......, por lo que mi ducenta es al definir el paginador y sort. Pero si no lo pongo estas dos caracteriasticas no muestra nada en la grilla. mi codigo en el component:

```
buscar(busqueda) {
    this.paginator = this.helperService.configurarPaginator(this.paginator);
    if (busqueda.fechaDesde > busqueda.fechaHasta) {
      this.messageService.showWarning("La fecha Desde no puede ser mayor a la fecha Hasta");
    }
    else {
      this.solicitud.nit = busqueda.nit;
      this.solicitud.fechaDesde = busqueda.fechaDesde;
      this.solicitud.fechaHasta = busqueda.fechaHasta;
      this.solicitud.motivoConsulta = busqueda.motivoConsulta;
      this.solicitud.nueva = true;
      this.solicitud.registroInicial = 0;
      this.solicitud.tamanioPagina = 10;
      this.serviceSubscription = this.reversionesService.getReversionesList(this.solicitud).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.reversiones = res;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
          //this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          //this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Ya revice algunas paginas donde tratan este error, pero creo el problema es por el json alguna sugerencia?.
aca el codigo mejorado para mapear y volverlo array, pero genera las filas sin datos, que puede estar mal?:

const mapped = Object.keys(res).map(key => ({value: res[key]}));
let a = Array.from( mapped.values() );

```
      for (let numero of a){
        if (this.num==2){
          //console.log(numero.value);
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(numero.value);
        }
        this.num=this.num+1;
      }
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: le estas pasando exactamente ese json al source del mattable? porque slice es una funcion de array no de objeto, además al mattable debes pasarle un array

Comment: el mismo json le estoy pasando al mattable.

Comment: pues ese es tu problema, debes usar un arreglo de objetos. https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource

Comment: const mapped = Object.keys(res).map(key => ({value: res[key]}));
          let a = Array.from( mapped.values() );
          
          for (let numero of a){
            if (this.num==2){
              //console.log(numero.value);
              this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(numero.value);
            }
            this.num=this.num+1;
          }

Comment: este codigo puse para mapear y recuperar el array, pero no puede obtener los valores, solo obtengo filas vacias.

Comment: de esa forma el datasource parece estar bien, quizás el problema esta en el html, podrías agregarlo a ver si hay algún detalle que ver ahí

Comment: hay que actualizar el mattable o el datasource????

Comment: el datasource es el que se actualiza

Comment: Correcto, Ya lo solucione, Una columna de mi mattable no era igual a una columna del json de respuesta. Gracias por la ayuda LPZadkiel